# Derivative of y(x)/x using chain rule and quotient rule get different results

Tags: derivatives

$$f(x) = \frac{y(x)}{x}$$

Use chain rule:
$$\frac{df(x)}{dx} = \frac1x\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}$$

Use quotient rule:
$$\frac{df(x)}{dx} = \frac{\frac{dy}{dx} \cdot x - y \cdot 1)}{x^2} = \frac1x \cdot\frac{dy}{dx} - \frac{y}{x^2}$$

Why are they different?
Where did I make mistake?

Comment: $\frac{y(x)}{x}$ is _not_ the composition of $\frac{1}{x}$ and $y(x)$, so trying to apply the chain rule doesn't work. I would suggest you take a look at the [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) on the subject.

Comment: @JeffreyChen I think you are a bit confused about the chain rule... The chain rule would be: If  $x = x(t)$ then
$$
\frac{df}{dt} = \frac{df}{dx}\cdot \frac{dx}{dt}.
$$

Comment: What kind of chain rule are you using? Chain rule is used on composite functions. How do you write $\frac{y(x)}{x}$ as a composition of two functions?

Answer (score 1):

Your use of the chain rule is wrong, any you can see this immediatelly if you set $y(x)=1$. In that case, $f(x)=\frac1x$, and its derivative should be $-\frac{1}{x^2}$.

However, you get $\frac{1}{x}\cdot \frac{dy}{dx} = 0$ in that case.

---

The mistake you make is in the very fact you use the chain rule **at all**. The chain rule can be used when you are calculating the differential of a **composition** of two functions.

For example, if $f(x)=\frac{1}{y(x)}$, then $f$ is the composition of two functions, in particular, $f=g\circ y$ where $g(x)=\frac1x$. And in this case, you can use the chain rule to get

$$\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{dg}{dx}\circ y\cdot \frac{dy}{dx}$$

or, on other words,

$$\frac{df}{dx}(x)=\frac{dg}{dx}(y(x))\cdot \frac{dy}{dx}(x).$$

---

But, as said above, your function cannot be written as a composition of some function and $y$, and so the simple chain rule cannot be applied.

Note that you **can** still use a more advanced version of the chain rule, because you can still write $f$ as a composition of twoo functions, in particular,

$$f = F(x, y(x))$$

where $F$ is a function from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$ defined as $F(x,y)=\frac{y}{x}$.

But if you use this definition, then you also need to use the correct chain rule, which says that if

$$f(x)=F(g_1(x), g_2(x)),$$

then $$\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\cdot \frac{dg_1}{dx} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\cdot \frac{dg_2}{dx} $$

and if you use this rule, then you also get the correct derivative.

Comment: You can write $f(x)= \frac{y(x)}{x}$ as a composition of two functions *easily*. $f = f \circ g$ where $g(x)= x$ but this isn't helpful, this is just being a smartass.

Comment: @Ibrahim You are correct, I edited that part of the post to "cannot be written as a composition of some function and $y$", to make it more clear and smartass-proof :D